# Why does leaflet.js not display all polygons in a multipolygon geojson file

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, utm

I am trying to render a grid defined in geojson using leaflet.js.  The grid is based on 10x10 cells defined using MGRS/UTM. It is defined as a MultiPolygon. A screenshot of the output is presented below.  The extents of the grid at the markers at the bottom left and the top right.  The grid is created by creating a polygon for each cell. In the example below, the right most row of cells and some other cells in the top right corner are missing.  When I used the same code on another location (the field to the right), cells in the centre and on the left were missing). I cannot post all the code here (there is too much) and the GeoJson files are too large. But I can guarantee that the Polygon for the top right cell is the last set of coordinates and it is not displayed.

[image: illustration of grid with missing polygons]

EDIT 1: It seems that both the mgrs and the utm python libraries return long-lat instead of lat-long for some coordinates. Still trying to understand why it might do this...

Comment: What do you get with other GeoJSON viewers with your file? E.g. there are some online viewers.

Comment: Just had a look using geojson.tools - the coordinate system changes randomly from long,lat to lat,long halfway through the coordinates....  Seems like it is a feature of the utm and mgrs libraries in python :)  will investigate further - thanks for the help.